# Javascript sum of values in table

Tags: javascript

I've succesfully used [this code](http://jsfiddle.net/QmTNZ/) to calculate sums in a table:

```
var $overall = 0;

$("tr.sum").each(function()
{

    var $qnt = $(this).find("td").eq(0);
    var $price = $(this).find("td").eq(1);

    console.log($qnt+" | "+$price);

    var sum = parseFloat($price.text()) * parseFloat($qnt.text());

    $(this).find("td").eq(2).text(sum);

    $overall+= sum;

});

$("#total").text($overall); });
```

I changed one line to avoid rounding errors:

```
var sum = parseFloat((parseFloat($price.text().replace(',', '.')) * parseFloat($qnt.text().replace(',', '.'))).toFixed(2));
```

It works fine. But I can't solve the problem to round the total sum to two decimal places.

```
 $("#total").text($overall);
```

I tried toFixed(2). But this results in a string and not a number.

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks, Mike

Comment: if you don't want trailing zeros to be truncated (1.00 -> 1) then you will need to be happy with the string representation of the value. Just remember to convert it back to a number when you work with it.

Comment: Number(sum).toFixed(2);

Answer (score -2):

after doing all calculation make it like this

```
$overall.toFixed(2);
```

Comment: What is wrong, if sum/overall = 10.12432, then after passing it toFixed(sum); it will return 10.12

Comment: Thank you very much, guys. $overall.toFixed(2); did the trick. Unfortunately, my question was marked as duplicate. Well, that's not exactly true. I knew .toFixed(2), but I didn't know how to exacly use it in this example. Well, it doesn't work in IE. But then, what works in IE? Again, thanks a lot!